# Why does my nested for-if loops load much slonger when I dont nest this? And can I possibly fix this?

Tags: c#, excel, if-statement, for-loop, nested

Sorry if the question if a bit vague, but the code is very complicated and I hope you will have the right eye to see and understand it :)

I will show 2 sort codes. The codes just read an excel sheet and depending on the text it contains, it will put them in a list. For example: I got an excel table:

`A1 = Peter` `D1 = hello`

`A2 = Frank` `D2 = bye`

`A3 = Jan` `D3 = hello`

`A4 = Obama` `D4 = hello`

The list `HELLO` will contain: D1, D3, D4
The list `BYE` will contain: D2

I first had this code to do it which runs pretty fast:

```
List<string> ARowList = new List<string>();
List<string> DRowList = new List<string>();
List<string> HELLO = new List<string>();
List<string> BYE = new List<string>();
List<List<string>> AllMeetingsLists = new List<List<string>>();
AllMeetingLists.Add (HELLO);
AllMeetingLists.Add (BYE);


for (int i = 1; !endReach; i++)
{            
    if   (excel_getValue("D"+i).Contains("HELLO"))
     {
      HELLO.Add(excel_getValue("A"+1) + "said hello how are you")
    }
    else if  (excel_getValue("D"+i).Contains("BYE"))
    {
      BYE.Add(excel_getValue("A"+1) + "said goodbye have a nice day")
    }
  Console.WriteLine(excel_getValue("A" + i));
   //This goes on for 30 more options of what it can contain
}
```

I made this to make it less code BUT this one runs much slower:

```
List<string> ARowList = new List<string>();
List<string> DRowList = new List<string>();
List<string> HELLO = new List<string>();
List<string> BYE = new List<string>();
List<List<string>> AllMeetingsLists = new List<List<string>>();
AllMeetingLists.Add (HELLO);
AllMeetingLists.Add (BYE);
List<string> ListWithAllSayings = new list<string>();
ListWithAllSayings.Add("hello");
ListWithAllSayings.Add("bye");
for (int j=0;j<ListWithAllSayings.Count;j++)
{
   if (excel_getValue("D" +1).Contains(ListWithAllSayings[j]))
   {
      AllMeetingLists[j].Add("said hello/goodbye: ("A" +i)") // I have to make anther lists off what will be added with the ("A" + i) BUT this is NOT the problem
   }
  Console.WriteLine(excel_getValue("A" + i));
}
```

This runs muuuuch slower than the other code.. While this code is much easier to change and much shorter. (How) can I fix this?

Comment: @Sayse Sorry, I just typed it and didnt copy my code, So I made a little mistake with `(` and `{` , thanks for noticing! I changed it

Comment: That is a huge waste of time. Copy and paste it into notepad++, format it, then paste it here.

Comment: @WhyCry Indeed, Will do that the next time, thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the chain of `if`-`then`-`else`s get terminated as soon as you find a positive match, while your loop goes on to try other strings. If you find the right value within the first few constant matches most of the time, the difference may be significant.

Adding a `break` on finding the first item will fix this problem.

Another thing you should do is moving the expression that obtains the cell out of the loop. You should also move the line that prints `excel_getValue("A" + i)` out of the loop, because in your modified code it gets printed on each iteration of the nested loop.

```
var valueAtDi = excel_getValue("D" +i);
for (int j=0;j<ListWithAllSayings.Count;j++) {
    if (valueAtDi.Contains(ListWithAllSayings[j])) {
        AllMeetingLists[j].Add("said hello/goodbye: ("A" +i)");
        break;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(excel_getValue("A" + i));
```

Comment: True, I actually got it out of the for-loop but with rewriting the code i misplaced it. Next time I will copy it in note-pad++ and change it. Anyway thanks for the tips, the break made it much faster, because most of the matches are high in the list. Thank you very much - Will mark as answers asap